# Copyright expiration

Tags: expiration, expired-patent, us2981578

In reference to the patent: [US 2,981,578](https://www.google.com/patents/US2981578)

I would like to know if the copy rights of this item are still in their period of validity.

Answer (score 2):

Copyright is not applicable, so I am assuming you mean "enforceable".

The patent in question has a Filing Date of May 20, 1959, a grant date of April 25, 1961, and is a continuation from an application with a Priority Date of May 2, 1957.

The patent, and its claims and subject matter have been in the Public Domain since April 25, 1978.